# Deduction in salary

Tags: salary, contracts

I just joined a company in Dubai 25 days back as a safety inspector.

According to agreement and offer paper they are supposed to pay me 3500 AED/Month, but today my manager called me that they can only pay me 2500 AED per month due to lack of experience in the safety field.

This deduction was made by our GM. I am really shocked after this. GM said that he will terminate me if I do not agree to this.

What should I do now? My medical is still on hold.

Comment: Do you have a contract, signed by them?

Comment: Contact your embassy. Ask them for advice. They may be able to refer you to an employment lawyer and other resources. Then change your name on StackOverflow. Do not post your real name on the internet for something like this. Unfortunately, I've heard many bad things like this happening in Dubai. http://www.bbc.com/capital/story/20140217-oasis-or-mirage-for-expats

Answer (score 2):

From a contract and even moral point of view, you are completely in the right.  You have a written contract, and they are violating it.

Now here's the problem...

It's going to be tough to get them to cough up the dough without filing a lawsuit.  Which would certainly poison the well with your employer.  Not to mention that the cost of a lawsuit might exceed the amount you're fighting over.

**High-level advice** -- At this point, I'm thinking you need to find yourself another job.  Start looking.  Consider how long it takes to find a job in your part of the world.

In the meantime...  your GM is trying to get you to agree to another salary "voluntarily", so that you *won't* have a cause for complaint in the future.  That's not too big a deal, as you're planning to leave (right?).  So now you're at the first decision point.  What to do immediately?  Options:

- **Accept the pay cut** -- This is the safest (and least satisfying) course, but you don't want to risk getting fired before you find your new position.
- **Accept the pay cut but not retroactively** -- That is, they owe you ~1 month at the original rate per contract, but you'll take the lower rate going forward.  Slightly riskier, but that's what I'd do, assuming I had enough financial reserve just in case they get mad and let me go.
- **Tell them you're holding them to your contract** -- That's the most satisfying option, but from what you've said above, you'll be enjoying yourself on the beach while you find a new job.

Okay, so once you find your new job, what then?  One or more of these:

- **Embrace serenity** -- just enjoy you being you
- **Revenge via Glassdoor** -- various sites allow ratings of companies.  You can *savage* them there for what they've done
- **Revenge in small-claims court** -- In my country (US), for amounts less than $5000 USD, you can go to this smaller, less scary court.  If there's an equivalent in Dubai you can sue them for the amount you were actually underpaid.  You can do this, if you're willing to invest a day in it, and if the UAE $1000 or so is important enough.

I'd probably do a little of all three.

Comment: Finding a new position in Dubai may be impossible if you're on a "limited contract". You may be required to pay the rest of your unearned salary to your employer for the remainder of your contract. And no other company in Dubai can hire you if the original company doesn't agree to transfer your visa to the new company. http://www.telegraph.co.uk/finance/personalfinance/expat-money/11898598/How-I-was-stung-by-my-UAE-employment-contract.html

Comment: @StephanBranczyk that's a good point; there may be a lot more local legal twists than people in my neck of the woods are aware of.  I should edit to mention that my advice is heavily influenced by the US environment I live in.